# Making queries for a single row table in Django

Tags: django

This may be a simple one. But I could not reason it out. I am using Django 1.7.2

I have a model where there is only one row of data in the table.

**Case 1 : objects.all()**

```
info = ModelName.objects.all()
```

I get the data but when I try to put it in a template, it is not getting displayed.

```
{% for item in info %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Case 2 : objects.get()**

```
info = ModelName.objects.get()
```

I get the data and it is getting displayed in template.

```
{{ info.name }}
```

**Questions:**

Could anyone explain why **case 1** is not working?

And in **case 2** using get() without any *pk* value is fine?

Comment: what is the result of `print info`? how to you pass variables?

Comment: `print info` gives a normal and valid Queryset result. I am passing variable using `return render(request, template_name, {'info': info})`

Comment: What about `print item` within the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Case 2 works fine, because the arguments for the `get()` function are optional. If you don't provide anything, it will match against every record. Since you table only has one, it raises no exception.

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get

Your case 1 should be working, though. Check if your `info` is in your context for the template.